# How do you find out how many people are following a certain post?

Tags: support, follow-posts

I need to know how popular one of my posts is. The more people it attracts, the greater the chance that someone can and will answer.

If it's not very popular, I need to ask my question differently.

The best way to determine the popularity of a post is *not* to check how many people have *viewed* it - anyway that information is readily available. However, a poorly written post can result in many views, but that doesn't mean anyone is interested once they see what the post *contains*.

What I need to know is how many people are *following* the post (not how many *followers* I have - that's the most common answer I got - even on Google search - when I looked for an answer to this question).

So, how do I find out how many people are actually following my post?

Comment: There are many factors that impact how many people see your post, that are out of your control. Please focus on writing the best *quality* question you can. That's how the site is supposed to work: you help build it by making a good question that belongs on the site, and we do our part to build the site by giving an answer (which only incidentally helps you as the asker). I know that description sounds cruel, but.

Answer (score 12):

Following a post is private, unlike bookmarking it, which is public. Whether anyone is following your post is something only known to moderators and authorized staff.

A count was requested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345713/188189) when following was originally implemented, and this was the Stack Exchange response...

> Sorry, this isn't going to happen. We are concerned that if posts have the number of followers marked, that they will become magnets for answer/comment spam.

> We don't have any plans to add it to SEDE at this time, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks, much obliged. It's after all better to know you *can't* do it than searching in vain for *how* to. Also a special thanks for removing my request for advise: it became moot, of course. 

Comment: Re *"become magnets for answer/comment spam"*: Couldn't the same be said for views?

Comment: @PeterMortensen indeed, although this comment might work better on the answer I linked as the poster of the comment might respond.